# Installing npm package with prepare script from yarn produces only index.js

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg

I have this sample typescript package with prepare script running `tsc`: https://github.com/richard-ejem/tspackage

When I install it with npm using `npm add git+https://github.com/richard-ejem/tspackage.git#master` to a project, `node_modules/tspackage/dist` contains 4 files as expected:

- index.js
- index.d.ts
- utils.js
- utils.d.ts

However, when installed with yarn using `yarn add git+https://github.com/richard-ejem/tspackage.git#master`, the `dist` folder contains only `index.js`.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in yarn? Is there some possible workaround/other way to build typescript git dependencies on yarn install?

Comment: Looks like for `yarn` you need to use the `"postinstall"` hook. https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/lifecycle-scripts

Comment: @AluanHaddad no, I tried that one, but it didn't build dist folder at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a solution - the trick is to add empty `.npmignore` file to the repository.

It is probably related to this problem: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5235#issuecomment-571206092

if there is no `.npmignore`, npm/yarn removes everything matching `.gitignore` on install, and in case of yarn, this somehow conflicts with `prepare` script. It is still weird that `dist/index.js` is not removed since it is ignored by `.gitignore` too, however the empty `.npmignore` solves the problem.

Comment: This trick didn't work for me (Yarn 1.22.5)

Answer (score 0):

Try add through ssh, `yarn add ssh://github.com/richard-ejem/tspackage#master`

Don't know why, but it worked for me, `yarn -v 1.22.15`